# How to output each number consecutively in an index every second?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval, console.log

I have the following loop:

```js
for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {  
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(index)
  }, 1000);
}
```

How can I make it so that it console logs 0 the first second, 1 the second second, 2 the third second, 3 the fourth second, 0 the fifth second, and so on until the interval is cleared?

Comment: Hint: It's incorrect to put `setInterval` inside the loop. What this is doing is immediately calling `setInterval` 5 times, whereas what you actually want to do is call `setInterval` once and just have it output a different number each time its callback is run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a more-or-less-but-rather-more elegant solution using a generator function.

Generator functions are useful here, as their execution can be paused by `yield`, and resumed by calling the generator object's `next` method:

```js
function* logger() {
  while (true) {
    for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
      console.log(index)
      yield
    }
  }
}

let generator = logger()
setInterval(() => generator.next(), 1000)
```

Or, again with generators, you can even `yield` the current `index`, and let the interval function log (or do anything else with) it:

```js
function* logger() {
  while (true) {
    for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
      yield index
    }
  }
}

let generator = logger()
setInterval(() => console.log(generator.next().value), 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var counter = 0,
  limit = 5,
  handle; // global vars

function start() {
  counter = 0;
  clearInterval(handle); // reset
  handle = setInterval(count, 1000); // interval handle
}

function count() {
  console.log(counter++); // increment counter
  if (counter >= limit) { // check limit
    clearInterval(handle); //  stop timer
  }
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(handle);
}

start();

setTimeout(function(){
start();
},3110); // reset while counting.
```

As mentioned in the comments added reset functionality.

Comment: This works nicely, thanks. How do I restart the interval once it's been cleared, so that it goes back to 0 after reaching 4?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy you only need wrap your code that starts counting with a function and call it when you need.