# Automatic tab switch in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I built a tabbing system with Javascript. Manually It works fine but i want it to work automaticaly.
I want an infinite loop where I iterate through each tab with the interval of 6sec and then start from the beginning of the tab again. and when the user click on a tab this loop should stop.

I've searched for solution but could'nt find anything for vanilla javascript or did'nt understand (i'm a biggener). most of the solutions are available in jquery. but I only want javascript.

here is the codepen for this problem [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Zaraa/pen/bGeXKWN?editors=1010)

Here is the sample Html code

```
<div id="tabs-id">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a onclick="changeAtiveTab(event,'tab1')"> Tab 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a onclick="changeAtiveTab(event,'tab2')"> Tab 2 </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a onclick="changeAtiveTab(event,'tab3')"> Tab 3 </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a onclick="changeAtiveTab(event,'tab4')"> Tab 4 </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content tab-space">
  <div class="block" id="tab1">
    <div class="container">Tab 1 content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" id="tab2">
    <div class="container">Tab 2 content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" id="tab3">
    <div class="container">Tab 3 content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" id="tab4">
    <div class="container">Tab 4 content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and Javascript

```
function changeAtiveTab(event, tabID) {
  let element = event.target;
  while (element.nodeName !== "A") {
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  ulElement = element.parentNode.parentNode;
  aElements = ulElement.querySelectorAll("li > a");
 
  tabContents = document
    .getElementById("tabs-id")
    .querySelectorAll(".tab-content > div");
  for (let i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
    aElements[i].classList.remove("border-t-4");
    aElements[i].classList.remove("font-bold");
    tabContents[i].classList.add("hidden");
    tabContents[i].classList.remove("block");
  }

  element.classList.add("border-t-4");
  element.classList.add("font-bold");
  
  document.getElementById(tabID).classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById(tabID).classList.add("block");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to output each number consecutively in an index every second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220387/how-to-output-each-number-consecutively-in-an-index-every-second)

Comment: @FZs thanks for the suggestion, but this is not the answer to my question. my question is about to add an automated function and then removing that function onclick.

Comment: You can clear the interval on click using `clearInterval()`. What's the part you don't understand? For me, it seemed like the solution over there could be used here... Just replace `console.log` with a call to `changeAtiveTab`

Comment: @FZs I've applied both suggested solutions and it still doesn't solve my problem, you can check here https://codepen.io/Zaraa/pen/bGeXKWN?editors=1111

Comment: It should be something like this: https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/qBNevNw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [*Interval Generator* (aka. *Async Loop*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220512/8376184) here,  by making some little changes to your code (open in full-page view for the tab buttons to appear):

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#tabs-id')
const ulElement = container.querySelector('ul')
const aElements = ulElement.querySelectorAll("li > a");
const tabs = container.querySelectorAll('.tab-content > div')


function changeAtiveTab(index) {
  for (let i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
    aElements[i].classList.remove("border-t-4");
    aElements[i].classList.remove("font-bold");
    tabs[i].classList.add("hidden");
    tabs[i].classList.remove("block");
  }

  aElements[index].classList.add("border-t-4");
  aElements[index].classList.add("font-bold");

  tabs[index].classList.remove("hidden");
  tabs[index].classList.add("block");
}


const generator = (function* logger() {
  while (true) {
    for (let index = 0; index < aElements.length; index++) {
      changeAtiveTab(index)
      yield
    }
  }
})()

const interval = setInterval(() => generator.next(), 4000)

for (let i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++)
  aElements[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(interval)
    changeAtiveTab(i)
  })
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap" id="tabs-id">
    <div class="w-full">
      <div class="hidden md:block">
        <ul class="flex w-3/4 mb-0 list-none flex-wrap mx-auto pt-3 pb-4 flex-row ">
          <li class="-mb-px last:mr-0 flex-auto text-center">
            <a class="text-sm  block pt-5 cursor-pointer leading-normal font-bold border-t-4 border-t-2">
              Tab 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="-mb-px  last:mr-0 flex-auto text-center">
            <a class="text-sm  block pt-5 cursor-pointer leading-normal border-t-2">
              Tab 2
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="-mb-px last:mr-0 flex-auto text-center">
            <a class="text-sm  block pt-5 cursor-pointer leading-normal border-t-2">
              Tab 3 
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="-mb-px last:mr-0 flex-auto text-center">
            <a class="text-sm  block pt-5 cursor-pointer leading-normal border-t-2">
              Tab 4 
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="relative flex flex-col min-w-0 break-words bg-white w-full ">
        <div class=" py-5 flex-auto">
          <div class="tab-content tab-space">
            <div class="block">
              <div class="container mx-auto w-2/4 bg-red-300 p-20"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden">
              <div class="container mx-auto w-2/4 bg-pink-300 p-20">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden">
              <div class="container mx-auto w-2/4 bg-blue-300 p-20">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden">
              <div class="container mx-auto w-2/4 bg-green-300 p-20">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try it on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/qBNevNw)