# How to make pause between each for loop iteration in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sorry if there has already been such question, I haven't found.

I wanna make a progress (loading) animation with JS:

```
   <div class = "load">

     <div id = "load_fill"></div>

     <p id = "percent">0%</p>

   </div>
```

```
   
   
   <script>
     
     let percent = document.getElementById("percent");
     let load_fill = document.getElementById("load_fill")
     
     
     
     let j = 0;
     
     let fill = ()  => {
       
       j++;

       percent.textContent = `${j}%`;

       load_fill.style.width = `${j}%`
       
     }

     
     for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       
       setTimeout(fill, 200);
       
     }
     
     
   </script>
```

The problem is that the first iteration works with delay but others no;

Is there any way to make delay between each iteration?

Will be thankful for any answer.

Comment: The calls to `setTimeout()` return immediately. 200 milliseconds later, all of them will happen in rapid succession. Multiply 200 by `i` to space them out.

Comment: I recommend you to use a generator function for this (like in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220512/8376184)), as it can make your code much cleaner.

Comment: @FZs. Thanks, the code really looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Array(100).map((el, ind) => ind).forEach((cur) => setTimeout(fill, (cur + 1) * 200))
```

Here, we space out each setTimeout by first creating a range array (the first part) before setting a time out 200 ms between each one.

Comment: Not sure about the efficiency though, but the main thing is that it worked - no problem!

Comment: I think that this is more efficient than my method (calling out a function for 100 times)

Comment: @YuraShtefanko Actually, it isn't that efficient: this calls functions 200 times but also needlessly allocates an array of 100 elements (or even more, if you want more than 100 iterations). A `setInterval` with an iteration counting mechanism, that calls `clearInterval` after 100 iterations would be the most efficient.