# Javascript: optimizing script for automatic changing image

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Javascript script that is looping **5 images** in the background.

The first image with class **trainer01** is already in the HTML file.

My script working fine but I really need to optimize it and have it **tidier**. Now when I need to change seconds between transitions I need to change setTimeout for each change and then setInterval.

So I need to have more tiny and optimized. Is there any option on how can I get it as written above?

**MY SCRIPT:**

```
const herotrainers = document.getElementById("herotrainers");

function trainerChanger() {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            herotrainers.className = '';
            herotrainers.classList.add('trainer02');
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(
        function() {
            herotrainers.className = '';
            herotrainers.classList.add('trainer03');
    }, 6000);

    setTimeout(
        function() {
            herotrainers.className = '';
            herotrainers.classList.add('trainer04');
    }, 9000);

    setTimeout(
        function() {
            herotrainers.className = '';
            herotrainers.classList.add('trainer05');
    }, 12000);

    setTimeout(
        function() {
            herotrainers.className = '';
            herotrainers.classList.add('trainer01');
    }, 15000);
}

trainerChanger();

setInterval(function() {
    trainerChanger();
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Try using loop synax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using generator functions for handling 'interval loops' (it uses the same approach as [my answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220512/8376184)):

```js
const iterator = function*(){
  const classNames = [
    'trainer01',
    'trainer02',
    'trainer03',
    'trainer04',
    'trainer05',
  ]
  const herotrainers = document.getElementById("herotrainers");
  
  while(true){ //Repeat indefinitely
    for(const elem of classNames){
      herotrainers.classList.add(elem)
      yield //Wait here
      herotrainers.classList.remove(elem)
    }
  }
}()

setInterval(() => iterator.next(), 3000)

iterator.next() //Call it immediately for the first time
```

```css
/* Some irrlevant stlyes to display the active class */
#herotrainers.trainer01::after{content:'.trainer01';color:red}#herotrainers.trainer02::after{content:'.trainer02';color:#ff0}#herotrainers.trainer03::after{content:'.trainer03';color:green}#herotrainers.trainer04::after{content:'.trainer04';color:#00f}#herotrainers.trainer05::after{content:'.trainer05';color:#ff00ff}
```

```html
<div id="herotrainers">Active class: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an async loop instead. There's no need to assign both the `className` and then do `classList.add` - just set the whole `className`:

```
const elm = document.getElementById("herotrainers");

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function trainerChanger() {
  for (let i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
    await delay(3000);
    elm.className = 'trainer0' + i;
  }
  await delay(3000);
  elm.className = 'trainer01';
  trainerChanger();
}

trainerChanger();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd store the interval criteria in an array, then loop through it.

Having the criteria in an array makes it easy to adjust.

```js
function trainerChanger () {
  const intervals = [
    {delay: 3000, className: 'trainer01'},
    {delay: 6000, className: 'trainer03'},
    {delay: 9000, className: 'trainer04'},
    {delay: 12000, className: 'trainer05'},
    {delay: 15000, className: 'trainer01'}
  ];

  intervals.forEach(interval => {
    const {delay, className} = interval;
    setTimeout(className => {
      herotrainers.className = className;
    }, delay);
  });
}
```