# Slow down a Javascript reduce loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, foreach, reduce

I would like to slow down a Javascript reduce loop to be able to visually simulate its effect. This is done within an observable notebook [link](https://observablehq.com/@dianaow/line-chart).

I have seen this example, but am encountering async issues in the Observable notebook. https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-slow-loop-javascript/

I have also considered using a setInterval for each iteration, but it doesn't make sense to use alongside reduce.

Comment: You'll have to write your own implementation of `reduce`. You could implement it as a *generator* so that you can control the execution of each iteration.

Comment: For practical purposes the `reduce` can still be used but instead of immediately applying the effects, it should compose together the visualisation effects into one, so after running it can re-run the visualisation with appropriate pacing. You'd probably need to show what and how you want to visualise. However, it's definitely possible to have a reducer function that takes two effects and produces a new one that is both with a pause between.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`setInterval`-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220460/8376184) to slow down the loop, but `reduce` isn't compatible with that (you can't `yield` inside it).

However, you can easily rewrite `reduce` to a `for..of` loop:

```js
const iterator = (function* () {
  const array = [1, 3, 5, 7]
  
  let acc = 0
  for (const elem of array) {
    console.log('Adding %f to %f', elem, acc)
    yield //Wait here
    acc += elem
  }
  
  console.log('Finished, result: %f', acc)
  clearInterval(interval) //Don't forget to clear the interval! Use a try..finally here if your code may throw!
})()

const interval = setInterval(() => iterator.next(), 1000)
```

Comment: That's pretty clever. I'd personally try to keep the generator more generic. Probably [something like this](https://jsbin.com/tadinogutu/1/edit?js,console). However, this is a pretty cool application of generators I never thought about - making a limited interval. It's a nice alternative to either doing `setTimeout` conditionally within the `setTimeout` or having to do conditional cancellation in a `setInterval`. It nicely encapsulates the logic elsewhere and you don't need an overly convoluted `setInterval`/`setTimeout` callback.